# By default datatype of literal 0 is int?

Tags: c#

By default datatype of 0 is int?

**Error:** *Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'.*

```
public short CardType { get; set; }
CardType = 0;
```

Even this statment is fine.

```
short CardType = 0;
```

**Note:** Its not matter of casting. I want to understand why 0 cannot be short by default?

Thank you for giving useful understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882497/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-short)

Comment: @FakeCaleb yes thats i want to understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820721/c-sharp-short-long-int-literal-format

Comment: @Ryan its not relevant.

Comment: @SAL: It’s extremely relevant. Particularly a comment on the top answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a numeric literal is, by default, an `int` unless you specify otherwise, for example a decimal can be declared using a `M`

```
var myDecimal = 0M;
```

`F` for float, `L` for long. But there isnt one for `short` you just need to rely on a cast:

```
public short CardType { get; set; }
CardType = (short)0;
```

---

On your edit:

> Its not matter of casting. I want to understand why 0 cannot be short by default?

Its not relevant - Integers have to be *some* data type by default, in this case they just default to an `int` as per the [Language specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx)

> The type of an integer literal is determined as follows:
>
> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by `U` or `u`, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `uint`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by `L` or `l`, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `long`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by `UL`, `Ul`, `uL`, `ul`, `LU`, `Lu`, `lU`, or `lu`, it is of type `ulong`.

Comment: A numeric literal is, by default, an int. got it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

```
public short CardType { get; set; }
CardType = (short)0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the type of `0` is an `int` in all the C-type languages; C# included.

There's no notation for a `short` literal.

So in those situations where the compiler cannot or is not allowed to disambiguate you need to use a cast:

```
CardType = (short)0;
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is type casting

```
CardType = (short)0;
```

you may want to see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)